# ExtJS: Associated idProperty's convert function not firing

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6

In my model, I have the idProperty as a composite key that I construct using the calculate function (also tried the convert function). However, it appears that whatever field you have set as the idProperty, the calculate/convert function will not fire. Is this covered somewhere in the docs? Also, how do I circumvent this? I could listen to the store's load and set the properties manually, I guess, but that's annoying. Also, I'm doing this all because I want to keep the grid's previous selection on refresh.

In the following example, you'll see the console.log does not fire, and thus, my selections will not persist when I click the "Refresh" button.  Here's the [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12as):

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.define('MyModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            idProperty: 'composite',
            fields: [{
                name: 'composite',
                type: 'string',
                calculate: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.name + data.num);
                    return ata.name + data.num;
                }
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'num',
                type: 'int'
            }]
        });
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'MyModel',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json'
            }
        });
        function onClickRefreshButton() {
            store.load();
        }
        var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
            text: 'Refresh',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                click: onClickRefreshButton
            }
        });
        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: store,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            title: 'My Grid',
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Num',
                dataIndex: 'num'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?293569

Comment: Ah, so it's a bug?  Thanks Evan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a [`transform`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-transform) function in your reader, like:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    transform: {
        fn: function(res) {
            return res.map(function(item) {
                item.composite = item.name + item.num;

                return item;
            });
         }
      }
 }
```

> If a transform function is set, it will be invoked just before
>   readRecords executes. It is passed the raw (deserialized) data object.
>   The transform function returns a data object, which can be a modified
>   version of the original data object, or a completely new data object.

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12bn

Comment: Very interesting and good call.  It's obviously not ideal, but it definitely works.  Thanks!  Any idea why convert/calculate don't work?

Comment: I think records can't get a calculated value because the id can't be changed, an the record must have an Id before the convert can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to not set the

```
idProperty: 'composite',
```

In that case the convert/calculate works as expected.

*Why convert/calculate is not called for idProperty:*

idProperty are unique and never change (which is a property of an ID) thus they don't support calculate or convert.

So they have to be set while creating the model.
Working code [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12bo)

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the whole reason behind setting the `idProperty` was to have the grid's row selection remain after hitting the refresh button.  I figured that was the reason why `idProperty` didn't change though... although, it would be nice if that was in the docs.